# How can I add different totals to a report in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I'm making a report in Visual Studio 2008 that gets its dataset from an SQL database that is grouped two different ways, let's say by `State` and `City`, and the important column in question is `Deposits`. As of now, I have placed the data in a table and added a subtotal of `Deposits` for each city. Is it possible to add a subtotal for each `State`, and then one huge grand total at the end of the report that totals the `Deposit` for each `State` into one number? Here's an example of how the table would look:

```
Alabama
Montgomery
            Deposits
            1000
            500
Subtotal:   1500

Springfield
            Deposits
            1000
            800
Subtotal:   1800

Total:      3300

Texas
Austin
            Deposits
            900
            500
Subtotal:   1400

Dallas
            Deposits
            800
            800
Subtotal:   1600

Total:      3000

Grand Total:6300
```

Comment: This seems perfectly possible. Have you tried it yet, using a tablix with grouping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two levels of grouping on your tablix, the first by State and the second by City. For the subtotals and grand total, in the group footers and the table footer put the following formula:

```
=Sum(Fields!Deposits.Value)
```

Reporting Services will do all the work for you.